# UIView animateWithDuration to resize view not working in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

I'm trying to resize my view when the keyboard becomes visible but its not working as I believe it should be.

First, I believe I have to `import QuartzCore` for the animations to work.

Then I basically just have this:

```
    let keyboardHeight = 280

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut  , animations: {
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height - keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

I believe this should just work. The frame does change, but its not animated!

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `keyboardHeight` and from where are you getting?

Comment: sorry about that. I hardcoded it. see my edit